# DataTables warning: JSON data from server could not be parsed. This is caused by a JSON formatting error

Tags: php, jquery, json, datatables

I am using server-side DataTables in a project

and do a search, shows me the following error message:

`DataTables warning: JSON data from server not could be parsed. This is Caused by a JSON formatting error.`

I found some suggestions in the forums but nothing has worked for me

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

check the network tab in firebug, you would probably see the underlying server error

Answer (score 1):

You're json is not in the valid format which datatables expects, that being row/column 2d array.

```
[["row1col1","row1col2"],["row2col1"],.....]
```

Comment: Enclosed in braces as well from the example: http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/ajax.html

Comment: I do not understand where the problem may be, the example I'm using for testing is as follows:

http://www.datatables.net/development/server-side/php_postgres

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem and it was as simple as updating the information in the following file:

```
    "sAjaxSource": "DataTables/examples/server_side/scripts/server_processing.php"
```

Don't know if the answer you're looking for is that pedestrian, but I figured I would throw in my 2 cents!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using :

```
"sAjaxSource": "myHandler.php"
```

Then you mus return from your handler:

```
"{\"aaData\": [{\"propOne\": \"valueOne\"},{\"propTwo\": \"valueTwo\"}], [...],... }"
```

Note

```
\"aaData\":
```

before json collection and note brakects:

```
{\"aaData\"....}
```

My example in asp.net(this is working):

```
Response.Write("{\"aaData\": [{\"propOne\": \"valueOne\"},{\"propTwo\": \"valueTwo\"}]}");
```

Client page:

```
      oTable = $('#myTable').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "aLengthMenu": [[5,10,20,50,100], [5,10,20,50,100]],
        "aaSorting": [[ 1, "desc" ]],
        "sAjaxSource": "MyHandler.ashx",
        "aoColumns": [
            { "mDataProp": "propOne" },
            { "mDataProp": "propTwo" }
        ]
    });
```

Comment: my handler return: 

"{"aaData": [{"propOne": "valueOne"},{"propTwo": "valueTwo"}], [...],... }", 

without the \

that is the problem?

or I can put the \ ?

Comment: Yes, datatable only accept double coma, this: {'propOne': 'valueOne'} give an error. DataTable needs "(double) so you need scape it with \.

Answer (score 0):

For newer versions of datatables,don't forget to remove this line from the server_processing.php file

```
/* REMOVE THIS LINE (it just includes my SQL connection user/pass) */
    include( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/datatables/mysql.php" );
```